# Why Cross-correlation work better than Generalized Cross-correlation GCC-PHAT in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, cross-correlation

```
Fs = 192000; 
t = 0:1/Fs:(0.01-(1/Fs));
F1 = 10000;  
x = 1*sin(2*pi*t*F1);

nSamplesGausswin = length(t);
w = (gausswin(nSamplesGausswin))';
s = w .* x;
```

this is my signal s that is a sine modulated by a gaussian window 
in the rest of the code I create two delayed function starting from this one and i had awgn with SNR = 10.
I wanna to calculate the time difference of arrival of these two signals using and using the less sophisticated algorithm gives me the better result. 
Anyone can explain me why? 
This is the indexes I use to delay the signals imaging a ra the signal have have to cover to reach the receiver at the speed of sound in water.

```
c = 1500;
ra = 10;
rb = 12;

na = ra/c;
nb = rb/c;

na = uint32(na/intSampling);
nb = uint32(nb/intSampling);
```

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to comment. Please show the two algorithms and the results with your actual waveforms  (plots help too)  to show what you mean by "better"

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry, i will give you more details: 
in the picture there are the signals that I created as a result of the propagation of the gaussian signals I described above. 
Figure 4 and 5 are the xcorr and the GCC calculated adding an awgn to the signals.
On the lower right you can see the different taus obtained with noisy signals and non-noisy signals:
-tau_ab is the correct value obtained from the clean signals = -0.0013
-tau_abNoisy is obtained with the xcorr = -0.0012
-tau_abNoisyGCC1 = -0.0049
I know that the noise is gaussian but the xcorr measures the better tau ad every cycle and I would like to understand why this happens. [image]

Comment: Please don't post new data as an answer, just edit the original question.